# Cloud Monitoring not working with Windows Server Core

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring

I installed the Cloud Monitoring agent on a GCP VM running Windows Server version 1909 Datacenter Core. This is not the containerized version which I read is not supported by Cloud Monitoring. I can not get the Cloud Monitoring data to show up on the Google console. I've been through all the steps in the "troubleshooting the agent" section of the Cloud Monitor docs, but nothing helps. I get the following warning in the Windows application log:

```
Error sending metrics to Stackdriver. Gateway API replied with a 403: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission denied (or the resource may not exist).",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

The troubleshooting docs suggest this error means the Monitoring Metric Writer role is not set, and yet it is set. I tried the API Explorer verification outlined under "verifying the agent data" in the troubleshooting docs, and get the following result:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
cache-control: private
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 39
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
date: Wed, 14 Apr 2021 20:12:37 GMT
server: ESF
vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer

{
  "unit": "By"
}
```

I don't know what this might indicate, but it is not the expected result listed in the docs. Not sure what else to look at. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Kirk

Comment: had you tried what was suggested in this thread from 2019 https://groups.google.com/g/google-stackdriver-discussion/c/Y0iX4UYHcMY ?

Comment: also, https://stackoverflow.com/a/53569295/946789

Comment: Thanks but doesn't help. I had tried almost everything suggested, and just tried adding access to all scopes as recommended in the second link, but no change in behavior.

Comment: Following the second paragraph on 3rd bullet of [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent/installation#before_you_begin)
“ If you are running very old Compute Engine instances or if you created Compute Engine instances without the default credentials, then you might not have the proper credentials. Did you follow [Authorizing the agent](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent/authorization) procedures?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I did try this by itself and in combination with other changes. Although the compute engine was not old, and already had the default credentials intact, I thought it was worth a try, but made no difference.